# Generate pages on the fly with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I'm new to PHP and I'm curious as to how you generate pages on the fly?

I have a table of users that I'm pulling from my DB and displaying on my homepage and that I know I can pass their user ID as a POST variable to 'mysite.com/profilepage.php' and then have a query on that page that would pull all relevant information for that ID, but say I wanted the page to be 'mysite.com/user-profiles/john-doe.php' ?

Would this be done with a `.htaccess` file? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Google for `url rewriting`.  You can turn a request for `user-profiles/john-doe.php` into `profilepage.php?username=john-doe`.

Comment: ^^^ not that *mysite.com/profilepage.php?id=7* is a worse idea than *mysite.com/user-profiles/john-doe.php* ignore all the SEO BS

Comment: Thanks guys,  just out of curiosity, if I pass the userID can I still use url rewriting to change the id to the name of that user automatically? bearing in mind there may be 300 users?

Comment: If it were me I'd drop the `.php`, file extensions are less and less common in web addresses. Rewrite rules will still be able to redirect to the right location after all.

Comment: you don't actully have to use rewrite rules at all, kiip it simple just use mysite.com/profilepage.php?id=7 profilepage.php, will use the id to get the data from the db

Answer (score 1):

If you must have the page be called `mysite.com/user-profiles/john-doe.php`, you can use URL rewriting as mellamokb mentioned in the comment to change the URL to that.

But as far as PHP is concerned, the way to do this is to create a PHP page (I'm going to suggest `user-profiles.php`), and then pass usernames to it with either `GET` or `POST`. Assuming that you're only reading and that the information in question is public, `GET` seems fine and it's easier to explain here.

You access the relevant page (generated "on the fly" by PHP) by pointing your browser to `user-profiles.php?username=John-Doe` and including code like this in `user-profiles.php`:

```
if ( isset($_GET['username']) )
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    // you now know the passed username
}
else
{
    // some kind of error handling for when there is no username
}
```

You now know you have the relevant username within your PHP file, and can use it to create the page as you want it. You can also use URL rewriting to change `user-profile.php?username=John-Doe` to `user-profiles/John-Doe` if you like.

**WARNING:** Do not use `$_GET` if the page in question is either going to be modifying the database in *any* way, or if it's going to be getting private information from the database. It is not in any way secure. Please read up on PHP security before creating pages that do either of those things.

Comment: Ahhh thanks @DragoonWraith, just out of curiosity, if I pass the userID can I still use url rewriting to change the id to the name of that user automatically? bearing in mind there may be 300 users?

Comment: The number of users shouldn't matter. I'm not sure what you mean by "change the id to the name of that user automatically". Unless you mean that "John-Doe" isn't the ID at all, but the ID is a number... I'm not sure on that but I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to PHP and havent looked at any frameworks, have a look at the [agiletoolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org).  It does some neat integration between jquery and php which will give you a nice look and feel to your pages.  It also encourages you to use ModelViewController (MVC) to segregate the parts of your code that are for database access and functionality from those which are purely for web page layout.

The options for URL rewriting mentioned above are the same but when a user is logged in, you have access to the user information from $this->api->auth('xxx') where xxx is the column in the users table.

The framework takes a little bit of learning but so does PHP and it's easy to get into very bad habits writing PHP code which means as the websites get bigger, you will find it harder to maintain your code.